# How to use Throttling while uploading the data to S3 using AWS .Net SDK

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application to upload files to Amazon S3 using AWS .net API.
My query is can we use throttling while uploading the data to S3? If I upload too many files from a single machine of small size say < 5MB  then my entire bandwidth is choked up. So is there a way to manage the bandwidth while uploading the data. We also tried with Low level .net API  and high level API  but there is no Attribute or API to set throttling.

Then I tried using Throttled Stream class of .net but this works smooth if I keep chunk size of 512KB and my current Network is of 2MBPS,  I'm still not sure is it because of throttled stream class or because of low chunk size that it works fine.

Below is my code:

```
   bps = (long)(1024 * ObjMetaData.MaxAvailSpeed * ((double)ObjMetaData.Bandwidth / 100.0));

   throttleStreamObj = new IUploader.ThrottledStream(ObjMetaData.FileStream, bps);

   fileTransferUtilityRequest =
                new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName(existingBucketName)
                .WithStorageClass(S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy)
                .WithMetadata(metaInfo)
                .WithPartSize(partSize)
                .WithKey(keyName)
                .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
                .WithTimeout(Int32.MaxValue - 1)
                .WithServerSideEncryptionMethod(ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256)
                .WithInputStream(throttleStreamObj) as TransferUtilityUploadRequest;
```

I followed the below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?